# Update of each row with random row value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to update each row of a table with a random row from another table (MSSQL 2008).

First create the data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Name
(
    Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO #Name VALUES ('Joe'), ('Bloggs'), ('John'), ('Smith')
SELECT * INTO #Name2 FROM #Name
```

Then set `#Name.Name` to a random row of `#Name2.Name`:

```
UPDATE #Name SET #Name.Name=(SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM #Name2 ORDER BY NEWID())
```

But `#Name.Name` is always the same value:

```
SELECT * FROM #Name

Name
----
Joe
Joe
Joe
Joe
```

How can the SQL be changed so that `#Name.Name` is random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a table is, by definition, an unordered set of rows, I don't really see the point of re-ordering the data in "random" order, especially in the absence of any other columns, but here is one pattern to accomplish this:

```
;WITH n1 AS (SELECT Name, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name)    FROM #Name),
      n2 AS (SELECT Name, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) FROM #Name2)
UPDATE n1 SET Name = n2.Name
  FROM n1 INNER JOIN n2 ON n1.rn = n2.rn;
```

Note that this assumes you simply want all names applied once, rather than true random (which would allow the same name to be selected more than once).